# android - Photo appears rotated in imagebutton

Tags: java, android, image

I have this code to show image in imagebutton after selected by the user.

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Uri selectedImageUri = data.getData();
    if (null != selectedImageUri) {
       // Set the image in ImageView
        _changePicture.setImageURI(selectedImageUri);
    }
}
```

My problem is that when a large image is selected then it is shown rotated 90 degrees left. I found some solutions here in stackoverflow.com but I can't use any of them as they use "Image" and I use "Uri" only.

EDIT:
using codes like this one:

```
public static void rotateImageIfRequired( Uri selectedImage) throws IOException {

        ExifInterface ei = new ExifInterface(selectedImage.getPath());
        int orientation = ei.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_NORMAL);

        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                Log.e(TAG,"ROTATE = 90");
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                Log.e(TAG,"ROTATE = 180");
                //return rotateImage(img, 180);
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_270:
                Log.e(TAG,"ROTATE = 270");
                //return rotateImage(img, 270);
            default:
                Log.e(TAG,"ROTATE = 0");
                //return img;
        }
    }
```

"ROTATE = 0" is returned. Some images are camera taken a few days ago. All of them are large. In small images no rotation takes place.

Comment: its nothing to do with the imagebutton. I assume you are getting the picture from the camera? You either need to request it in the orientation you want, or rotate it manually yourself and resave it

Comment: I know that. I do not know how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try using [Picasso Library](http://square.github.io/picasso/)? You can follow their samples on GitHub if you want to learn more about it.

For loading an image from device you can use:

```
File f = new File("path-to-image/image.png")
```

or

```
File f = new File(uri)

Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(f).into(imageView);
```

or

```
Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(uri).into(imageView);
```

Picasso also provides image transformations:

```
Picasso.with(context)
  .load(url)
  .resize(50, 50)
  .centerCrop()
  .into(imageView)
```

Comment: Glad I could help ! Happy Coding ! :)